# Persist entities unless they are already existing?

Tags: java, jpa, datanucleus

Consider the following JPA entity:

```
@Entity
class Entity {
    @Id
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

Entity entity = new Entity();
entity.setName('foo');
```

Inside a transaction, I would like to achieve the following: Persist the entity `entity` to the datastore if no other entity of that kind with name `foo` exists, or throw an exception if there is already an entity of kind `Entity` with name `foo`.

What is the most idiomatic/the best way to achieve this? (For what is's worth, I'm using DataNucleus' JPA implementation with App Engine.)

Comment: Wouldn't you already get an exception if you tried to persist a second entity with the same name, since name is the PK?

Comment: Actually this is what I was hoping for. However, I am able to overwrite an existing entity with a call to `persist`.

Comment: GAE/Datastore doesn't have such constraints in the datastore hence why you can overwrite existing records. Not an RDBMS

Comment: @BillyFrost: Out of curiosity, would/should it work with a fully compliant JPA provider/backend out of the box or would I need further annotations?

Comment: There is no "fully compliant JPA provider" for GAE/Datastore, but yes the idea of JPA is that it should throw an exception. I understand that Google didn't put enough effort into completing the job FWIW

Comment: Is there some documentation where the JPA provider for GAE/Datastore fails/has to fail short?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you create a new entity where you *explicitly specify the key*, you **must** check if an entity with the same key already exists in the datastore.

Create a method like:

```
public Entity getEntityByName(String name) {
    // First try to load from datastore
    // If exists, return that
    // If doesn't exist, return a new instance
}
```

And whenever you want to work with an `Enity`, acquire it via this method.

Comment: Plus remember that web app runs in concurrently executing environment (app server). **You need this method to be enclosed in a singleton**, otherwise another thread (another request) can create and persist an instance after you check for existence but before persisted.

Comment: I would have wrappped in Guice's `@transactional`.